# Groovy: the simplest way to detect duplicate, non-consecutive values in a list

Tags: groovy

I know that in Groovy,
if

```
list = [1,2,3,1]
```

when

```
list.unique()
```

with return

```
[1,2,3]
```

But if I want to detect duplicate value for duplicate, non-consecutive items in a list. How can I do this?

```
detect([1,2,3,1]) => true
detect([1,2,3,2]) => true
detect([1,1,2,3]) => false
detect([1,2,2,3,3]) => false
detect([1,2,3,4]) => false
```

Thanks.

Edit:
add these two cases

```
detect([1,2,2,1]) => true
detect([1,2,1,1]) => true
```

true means any non-consecutive, duplicate occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to `metaClass` list and add your own `detect` method as below:

```
List.metaClass.detect = {
  def rslt = delegate.inject([]){ ret, elem ->
      ret << (ret && ret.last() != elem ? elem : !ret ? elem : 'Dup')
  }
  return (!rslt.contains('Dup') && rslt != rslt.unique(false))
}

assert [1,2,3,1].detect() == true //Non-consecutive Dups 1
assert [1,2,3,2].detect() == true //Non-consecutive Dups 2
assert [1,1,2,3].detect() == false //Consecutive Dups 1
assert [1,2,2,3,3].detect() == false //Consecutive Dups 2 and 3
assert [1,2,3,4].detect() == false //Unique no dups
```

Comment: Very great! 

I just want to know how to does `!ref` mean an empty list in your code?

Comment: Yes exactly. I can try optimizing the metaClass implementation more if it can be more groovier.

Comment: oops, `[1,2,2,1].detect()` and `[1,2,1,1].detect()` return false, but I think that it should be true. I miss these two cases when I define the question.

Comment: How can they be true? They have consecutive dups, right? matching to your question criteria? This would contradict your problem statement.

Comment: I should define more clearly, true means non-consecutive dups occur. Sorry for my unclearness.

Comment: Yes exactly, that is what you had in your question earlier. non-consecutive dups returns true, consecutive dups return false.:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30879/discussion-between-dmahapatro-and-harold-chan)

Answer (score 13):

This should do it:

```
List list = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "d", "c", "a"]
```

and

```
list.countBy{it}.grep{it.value > 1}.collect{it.key}
```

Answer (score 8):

In case you need to obtain duplicate elements:

```
    def nonUniqueElements = {list ->
        list.findAll{a -> list.findAll{b -> b == a}.size() > 1}.unique()
    }

    assert nonUniqueElements(['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c']) == ['b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 6):

To determine whether a collection contains non-unique items (your first two examples), you can do something like this:

```
def a = [1, 2, 3, 1]   
boolean nonUnique = a.clone().unique().size() != a.size()
```

(Note that `unique()` modifies the list).

Meanwhile, `Collection.unique()` seems to do what you asked as far as 'grouping' items (your last three examples).

Edit: `unique()` works properly regardless of whether the collection is sorted.

Comment: Thanks! But this method cannot detect consecutiveness of list item, can it?

Comment: No, it can't - it wasn't clear that that is what you were asking for.

Answer (score 1):

To know if it has duplicates:

```
stringList.size() == stringList.toSet().size() // if true, it has no duplicates
```

To know which values are duplicated, you can do something like this:

```
class ListUtils {

    static List<String> getDuplicates(List<String> completeList) {
        List<String> duplicates = []
        Set<String> nonDuplicates = new HashSet<>()
        for (String string in completeList) {
            boolean addded = nonDuplicates.add(string)
            if (!addded) {
                duplicates << string
            }
        }
        return duplicates
    }

}
```

And here its Spock test case:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class ListUtilsSpec extends Specification {

    def "getDuplicates"() {
        when:
        List<String> duplicates = ListUtils.getDuplicates(["a", "b", "c", "a"])

        then:
        duplicates == ["a"]
    }

}
```